# Switching from Capacity Scheduler to Fair Scheduler on Hortonworks Data Platform

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

My organization is currently using Hortonworks HDP to manage our Hadoop Cluster. The default YARN scheduler is the Capacity Scheduler. I would like to switch to a Fair Scheduler. I am completely new to HDP.

In the absence of a cluster management suite, this would be done by editing the *yarn-site.xml* and changing the `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class` property to `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler`
and creating an extra *fair-scheduler.xml* file to specify the queue configurations as mentioned [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html) and then referring YARN to that configuration by setting the `yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file` property in *yarn-site.xml*.

Now in Ambari, while it is possible to change the `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class` property via the UI, and add a new custom property `yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file`, I cannot (for the love of god) find a way to have ambari read *fair-scheduler.xml* instead of *capacity-scheduler.xml*.

So my question is; How do I go about switching to the fair scheduler via Ambari? There's got to be an easy way, right?

[Properties in capacity-scheduler.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj6Gv.png)

Answer (score 2):

On your RM node, set yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file with the **full path** of your fair-scheduler.xml (or in custom yarn-site under ambari)

```
tail -n 1000 /var/log/hadoop-yarn/yarn/hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager-master.log | grep "fair-scheduler.xml"
```

After a restart of your ResourceManager, you should see that it is loading your file:

```
2019-02-19 15:49:26,358 INFO  fair.AllocationFileLoaderService (AllocationFileLoaderService.java:reloadAllocations(230)) - Loading allocation file file:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/fair-scheduler.xml
```

Works on Hdp 3.1.1, and probably 3.0.0 too

Comment: In Ambari, add yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file property to the custom yarn-site.xml

Comment: In case of error, below config setting
yarn.scheduler.capacity.ordering-policy.priority-utilization.underutilized-preemption.enabled=false `code`

ERROR:
service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:noteFailure(267)) - Service SchedulingMonitor (ProportionalCapacityPreemptionPolicy) failed in state INITED
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler not instance of org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler